# How to include blackboard bold letters from MathType into latex?

Tags: math-mode, texshop, blackboard

Whenever I try to copy blackboard bold letters from mathtype, I receive a translation error, saying that there is no translation available. How would I go about fixing this for the available characters?

Also, is there a way to add other blackboard-bold letters into the program, other than the ones already included, e.g E for expectation?

Answer (score 2):

In MathType, if you choose *AMS-LaTeX* in Cut and Copy Preferences, it will translate the Blackboard Bold capital letters, as well as the lower-case k. If you must use the *LaTeX 2.09 and later* translator, I can help you change the translator file to add those characters.

Comment: As you've mentioned, I typically need to use LaTeX 2.09. I've tried editing the translator file but with limited success.

Comment: Ok, I can send you a modified file, but even though you're using LaTeX 2.09 from MathType, you must use the `{amssymb}` or `{amsmath}` package in your document, as @Andrew mentioned. If that's OK, email us at support at dessci dot com and I'll send you the modified file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\usepackage{amssymb}` and select `AMSLatex` in cut copy preferences in Mathtype.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does this differ from the existing answer?

Comment: @TeXnician I think because it includes the requirement for a package at the LaTeX end too

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if I understand your question correctly.  The command to use blackboard bold letters in LaTeX is `\mathbb{X}`.  Make sure to load loaded a font package containing a double-struck alphabet.

If you loaded `unicode-math` rather than legacy font packages, you can additionally paste Unicode math symbols into your document directly.

You can load the Holey Roman font from Mathtime Pro 2 into LaTeX with `\usepackage[bb=mth]{mathalfa}`, or the regular Mathtime Pro blackboard bold with `\usepackage[bb=mt]{mathalfa}`. If it’s not the right height, you might want to add the `bbscaled=` option inside the brackets, such as `\usepackage[bb=mth, bbscaled=0.95]{mathalfa}`.